# NodaTime supports relative time display?

Tags: nodatime

I have a situation where the relative time is more important to a user than an absolute time. So it's more important to be able to quickly say "event happened 5 days and 5 hours ago" than "event happened at 1 PM CDT and it's 5 PM CST 5 days later now."

We store our dates in UTC and convert to display for the user:

```
pDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(pDateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[pCurrentUser.PreferredTimezone];
return Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(pDateTime).InZone(dateTimeZone).ToString("HH':'mm':'ss' 'MM'/'dd'/'yy' 'x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

We'll be using NodaTime 1.2 when it's fully out and just used vanilla ToString before.

However, times using this pattern end up using the daylight status of the time as opposed to the current daylight status. This means that times look something like: `16:15:32 10/25/13 CDT` even though we have now transitioned to CST.

It is an absolute measure of the time. This forces the user to do the logic: "How long ago was that? Is it daylight saving time now? If so, the difference is x. If not, I have to add or subtract an hour? That makes the difference y."

Meanwhile, a relative measure of the time would display `15:15:32 10/25/13 CST` in the absence of DST. This forces the user to do no conversions and allows them to compute what that time means in context much easier.

In a display that has numerous dates, it can get tricky to do the absolute time logic over the entire set. Doing it once is tricky to get right. However, a friendly relative string like "posted 5 hours ago" also forces them to resolve both the date and time themselves - that information is still important.

A compromise might be to do the posted blank hours/minutes ago for the first 24 hours or to include both the friendly string and absolute time - these are both patterns I've seen done.

But ignoring those, is there a way in NodaTime to imbue a time with a specific daylight status in order to get times displaying in a relative context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, times using this pattern end up using the daylight status of the time as opposed to the current daylight status. This means that times look something like: 16:15:32 10/25/13 CDT even though we have now transitioned to CST.

Yes, and it should. Displaying a date/time with CST despite that date/time occurring in CDT would be very odd, IMO.

> So it's more important to be able to quickly say "event happened 5 days and 5 hours ago" than "event happened at 1 PM CDT and it's 5 PM CST 5 days later now."

In that case you shouldn't be displaying a date/time at all, in my view. Convert both `ZonedDateTime` values to `Instant`, take the `Duration` between them, and then you can see that it's 5 days and 5 hours ago. (I can't remember how much help we provide with that - you may need to manually take the number of ticks and divide by `NodaConstants.TicksPerStandardDay` etc. Look at `DurationPattern` to see if it helps though.)

Alternatively, if you really want to display a date and time, but still easily be able to extract the difference between them mentally, two options suggest themselves:

- Use `OffsetDateTime` instead; there you *could* force the offsets to be the same, although I still think it would be odd to display an offset which wasn't actually the current offset in the zone you were observing the time in. Or you could just display the relevant offset at the time, so -5 for CST and -4 for CDT.
- Just display everything in UTC, so that daylight saving transitions are irrelevant.

Note that you *can't* get months between the two `ZonedDateTime` values, as we're dealing with an elapsed time (a duration) rather than calendar-logical arithmetic (a period).

Comment: I agree that the default is a completely sensible approach. Displaying everything in UTC just shifts the onus to the user to resolve all time differences (but I suppose is more effective than displaying the absolute times). Consider the case where a daylight shift happens in say, a forum. A post with a later time in the lexical sense shows up before a post with an earlier time in the lexical sense. The time of the post is important and the ordering is very confusing. Effectively, I guess I'm asking if there's a way to map a time to an invalid time (either ambiguous or nonexistent).

Comment: @Joel: Yes, it's confusing - because DST is confusing. In your forum example, posts with lexically later times *should* show up earlier than lexically earlier times if they actually represent later times in UTC. Pretending that DST didn't change isn't the right answer, IMO. I still don't have much context of what you're actually trying to do, but I think the way you're proposing could easily end up being *even more* confusing. Another option is to display both local times *and* the elapsed time between the two. If you give more context, it would be easier to help.

Comment: I think you've convinced me that trying to make it less confusing is basically impossible. The presence of ambiguous times means that even if I had a relative time display, you'd _still_ see weird artifacts. I don't like forcing the user to do more mental lifting than they have to, but every solution has downsides that will require it. Wish I could vote to have a single unambiguous world time.